# Lambda calculus reduction of functions

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm very new to lambda calculus and while I was reading a tutorial , came across with this.
Here is my equation.

```
Y = ƛf.( ƛx.f(xx)) ( ƛx.f(xx))
```

Now if we apply another term, let's say F (YF), then how can we reduce this.If I'm correct according to beta reduction , we can replace all the **f** in  **( ƛx.f(xx))** by **( ƛx.f(xx))**, is this correct and if so how can we do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reuction steps:

```
Y = ƛf.( ƛx.f(xx)) ( ƛx.f(xx)) = ƛf.( f ( ƛx.f(xx) ƛx.f(xx) ) ) 
  = ƛf.( f ( f (ƛx.f(xx) ƛx.f(xx)))) 
  = ƛf.( f ( f ( f (ƛx.f(xx) ƛx.f(xx)))) 
  = ƛf.( f ( f ( f ( f (ƛx.f(xx) ƛx.f(xx))))) = ...
```

So this Lambda term goes into an infinite loop...

**Explanation:**
Let's look on the term `( ƛx.f(xx) ƛx.f(xx) )` we substitute `ƛx.f(xx)` with `f'` 
which means `(f' f')` => activating the term `f'` on itself.
It might be easier to look at like this:
`( ƛy.f(yy) ƛx.f(xx) )` now when you activate the `ƛy.f(yy)` and provide the input (which substitutes `y` with `ƛx.f(xx)` ) the outcome is: `f(ƛx.f(xx) ƛx.f(xx))` which in turn, can go over the same process again and again and the lambda-expression will only expend...

**Remark:**
It's wrong to write:
`Y = ƛf.( ƛx.f(xx)) ( ƛx.f(xx))`
it should actually be:
`Y = ƛf.(ƛx.f(xx) ƛx.f(xx))`
The difference between `ƛx.f(xx)` and `(ƛx.f(xx))` is that the latter is an activation of `ƛx.f(xx)` - it's meaningless to activate it like this `(ƛx.f(xx))` since we need an `x` (input) to activate it on.
**Finally:**
`Y = ƛf.( ƛx.f(xx)) ( ƛx.f(xx)) = ƛf.( f ( ƛx.f(xx) ƛx.f(xx) ) )` 

meaning:
`YF = ( ƛx.F(xx)) ( ƛx.F(xx)) = F(ƛx.F(xx)) ( ƛx.F(xx)) = F(YF)`

Comment: Could you please tell me the steps to follow or the techniques I may use

Comment: I don't get how you got ƛf.( f ( ƛx.f(xx) ƛx.f(xx) ) ) Could you please tell the theorem used

Comment: So if we write an activation like YF, is it equals to `( ƛx.F(xx)) ( ƛx.F(xx))`

Comment: `( ƛx.F(xx))` is an activation of `ƛx.F(xx)` without parameters (which means nothing on our case cause it can be activated only on a parameter). Not sure what did you mean by YF though.

Comment: I came across this while trying to prove that Y is a first point combinator. So my goal is to prove that if F is any term then F(YF) = YF